# The method thenReturn(Future<String>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Future<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am writing JUnit test cases for one of my applications. I am new to JUnit framework. I have multiple If conditions, null condition, Please review test case method and suggest about below error. Please suggest How we can write test cases for If conditions, null conditions and environment variable.

**I am getting below error :**

```
The method thenReturn(Future<String>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Future<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

**For below line.**

```
when(executorService.submit(new AuditExecutor(reqMap, endpoint_start, restTemplate))).thenReturn("Success");
```

Please see below service class method.

```
public synchronized boolean preExecutionAudit(String auditpoint , Object obj) {

LOG.debug("Processing Auditing request");
Map<String, String> reqMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

try {

        if (null == configMap) {
            LOG.debug("Initiating request for AuditPoint Configuration");
            //configMap = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint_config, Map.class);
            setConfig();
            // For Backward Compatibility. To be refactored after all services standardize
            // the environment variables
            if (null != System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)) {
                LOG.debug("Central Config taking precedence "
                        + System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR));
                endpoint_register = System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)
                        + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONTEXT + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_REGISTER;
                endpoint_registerauditpoint = System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)
                        + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONTEXT + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_REGISTER_AP;
                endpoint_start = System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)
                        + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONTEXT + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_START;
                endpoint_end = System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)
                        + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONTEXT + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_END;
                endpoint_config = System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)
                        + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONTEXT + AuditConstants.REL_PATH_CONFIG;
                auditFilterInfo = new HashMap<>();
                auditFilterInfo.put(AuditConstants.AUDIT_FILTER_FIELD_REQ_ID,
                        AuditConstants.AUDIT_FILTER_METHOD_REQ_ID);// This need to be generalized if demands
                                                                    // more fields
            } else {
                LOG.debug("Relying on Local Config......");
            }

        } else {
            LOG.info("AuditPoint Configuration Cached");
        }

        if (null != configMap && configMap.containsKey(auditpoint)) {
            LOG.debug("Audit Point is Registered" + configMap);
            if (null != obj) {
                reqMap.put(auditpoint, new Gson().toJson(obj));
            } else {
                reqMap.put(auditpoint, null);
            }
            executorService.submit(new AuditExecutor(reqMap, endpoint_start, restTemplate));
        } else {
            LOG.debug("Audit Point is NOT Registered ");
            reqMap.put(auditpoint, "NO Object Required");
            executorService.submit(new AuditExecutor(reqMap, endpoint_registerauditpoint, restTemplate));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Start Audit Failed and Failure Ignored " + auditpoint, e);
}

return true;
}
```

**I have written below test case method for above service class method.**

```
@Test
void preExecutionAuditForIfCondition() {
    // when(configMap).thenReturn(null);
    when(auditLibService.setConfig()).thenReturn(configMap);
    when(System.getenv(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn("Success");
    Map<String, String> reqMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String auditpoint = "";
    String endpoint_start = "";
    reqMap.put(auditpoint, null);
    when(executorService.submit(new AuditExecutor(reqMap, endpoint_start, restTemplate))).thenReturn("Success");

    Object obj = null;
    boolean value = auditLibService.preExecutionAudit(auditpoint, obj);
    assertEquals(true, value);
}
```

Here submit is a inbuilt function.

```
submit() is a Inbuilt method. Please see below method definition.                                                                     
<String> Future<String> java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit(Callable<String> task)


submit
<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns aFuture representing the pending results of the task. TheFuture's get method will return the task's result uponsuccessful completion. 
If you would like to immediately block waitingfor a task, you can use constructions of the form result = exec.submit(aCallable).get(); 
Note: The Executors class includes a set of methodsthat can convert some other common closure-like objects,for example, PrivilegedAction to Callable form so they can be submitted.
Type Parameters:T - the type of the task's resultParameters:task - the task to submitReturns:a Future representing pending completion of the taskThrows:RejectedExecutionException - if the task cannot bescheduled for executionNullPointerException - if the task is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stub the `executor.submit(...)` by doing

```
Future mockFuture = mock(Future.class);
when(mockFuture.get()).thenReturn("Success");
when(executorService.submit(any(Callable.class))).thenReturn(mockFuture);
```

Submit is returning `Future<T>` while you are passing only the `String`

Comment: Hi @convexmethod,Thanks for your answer. I tried with doNothing.when() method, getting error for doNothing method. Could you please explain bit more with one line code example so I can understand properly ?

Comment: is `executorService.submit()` a trully void method?
`doNothing().when(..)` method should be written as:
`doNothing().when(executorService).submit(any(AuditExecutor.class));`

Notice, that `when` clauses contain only the service, and method is written after the clauses.

Comment: Hello @convexmethod, Submit is a inbuilt function. please see above post. I have updated post and mentioned submit method definition also.

Comment: Hi @convexmethod, Thanks for your answer, still in doubt. Do I need to use Callable.class or AuditExecutor.class. If I am using Callable.class getting CTE - The method submit(Callable<T>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Matcher<Callable>)